# what's this JS code doing

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

What is that code doing?

```
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(fileContent.length);
var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
for (var i=0; i!=fileContent.length; ++i)
    view[i] = fileContent.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
```

in context of function of FileSaver.js

```
saveAs(new Blob([buf],{type:""}), filename);
```

I cant get the entire goal of this code (except the last string, that saves the buf), cant get why are we changing *view* if we're saving *buf*, and how is *view* corresponds to the *buf*, and what is that *fileContent.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF* command means?

Comment: How much *do* you know of Javascript? Do you know what the notation `& 0xFF` means? What `charcodeAt()` does?

Comment: Start by looking up the different methods on MDN, [here's Uint8Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) etc. Read what they do, and test them out, and try to figure it out, you'll learn something along the way.

Comment: @Jongware `Barmar` had answered some questions below. I dont know what's the logical meaning of `& 0xFF`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`charCodeAt(i)` gets the `i`th character of the `fileContent` string, and returns its character code as a number. `& 0xFF` performs a binary `AND` operation between that number and the hexidecimal number `0xFF`; which masks it to the low-order 8 bits. Then this stores that 8-bit number into `view[i]`.

So this whole thing is essentially copying the string from `fileContent` to `buf`, but stripping off any high-order bits to get 8-bit characters.

The explicit masking here is not really necessary. Assigning to a `Uint8Array` automatically assigns the value modulo 256.

Comment: Question. Is Javascript sufficiently different from other languages that it is in fact possible to store a non-8-bit value in an array defined as `Uint8Array`?

Comment: Thanks, but what's the entire goal of this code? How is `buf` array changing, if we're changing the `view` array? What's the logical meaning of the binary `AND` with `0xFF`?

Comment: `AND` with `0xFF` returns the low-order 8 bits. I.e. it discards the high-order bits of multi-byte characters. I.e. this is converting the string to 8-bit ASCII.